# Was the phrase "taking my talents" a common phrase before LeBron James used it?

Tags: phrase-origin

Before LeBron James announced that he was "[taking his talents to South Beach](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTeCc8jy7FI)", was this common phrase, or did he create it? I seem to read or hear that phrase used very commonly now but I can't recall ever seeing it before.

Comment: Slightly tangential, but worth mentioning, imo: *Taking Your Talent to the Web* (New Riders, 2001), a truly excellent book by Jeffrey Zeldman, is now [freely downloadable](http://www.zeldman.com/2009/04/16/taking-your-talent-to-the-web-is-now-a-free-downloadable-book-from-zeldmancom/).

Comment: @Dori - Not at all tangential, as it predates LeBron saying it by quite a few years.

Answer (score 2):

I can find it in [Agatha Christie's Secret Adversary (1922)](http://books.google.com/books?id=R622OoTwKqAC&lpg=PA273&dq=%22taking%20my%20talents%22&pg=PA273#v=onepage&q=%22taking%20my%20talents%22&f=false) as one example before LeBron. There are others on Google Books.

> When I was a boy I heard a famous murder trial. I was deeply impressed by the power and eloquence of the counsel for the defence. For the first time I entertained the idea of **taking my talents** to that particular market

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even call that a specific coinage; I think it's just an instantiation of a general "taking my X to Y" phrase that's long established.